# web api put is recognizing query strings but not body

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

when i pass in users as a query string (using params in $http) and set the web api method to look for them in the uri everything is peachy.  but when i pass them in as below, users shows up as null.  what am i missing here?

angular function

```
scope.saveChanges = function () {
        // create array of user id's
        var users = [];
        angular.forEach(scope.usersInRole, function (v, k) {
            users.push(v.Key);
        });

        var data = { user: users };

        var token = angular.element("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

        // put changes on server
        http({
            url: config.root + 'api/Roles/' + scope.selectedRole + '/Users',
            method: 'PUT',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: { "X-XSRF-Token": token },
            xsrfCookieName: '__RequestVerificationToken'
        }).success(function (result) {
            // notify user changes were saved
            angular.element('#myModal').reveal({ closeOnBackgroundClick: false });
        });
    };
```

web api action

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Put(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromUri]string role, [FromBody]string[] user)
            {

                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
            }
```

Comment: try: `data: users` instead of `data: data`

Comment: well i'll be the son of a monkey's uncle.  so simple.   put that in an answer so i can mark it and give you credit.

Comment: i am curious though as to why just passing in the array to data works so cleanly and passing in how i have it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try: `data: users` instead of `data: data`.

In asp.net api, **the whole request body** is bound to a parameter. For this reason, you **cannot have multiple parameters** with the `[FromBody]` in the action method parameters. There is only one => we don't need to specify a property name in the request body.