# Binding json to web api action call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

What is the proper way of binding a JSON  to web api action parameter. For example, I have this JSON coming from browser client

**JSON**

```
{"model":[{"firstName":"Vivian","lastName":"Richards","game":0},
          {"firstName":"Diego","lastName":"Maradona","game":"1"}]}
```

**C# model**

```
public class Player {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FirstName { get; set; }
    public int LastName { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

**Web API Action**

```
// POST: api/Players
public IHttpActionResult PostPlayers(List<Player> model) { 
    //model bound is null here
    ....
}
```

**Raw Request**

```
POST http://localhost:xxxxx/api/Players HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:xxxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 120
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:xxxxx
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:xxxxx/assets/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6

{"model":[{"firstName":"Vivian","lastName":"Richards","game":0},{"firstName":"Diego","lastName":"Maradona","game":"1"}]}
```

To aid the javascript CamelCase I have following in the **WebApiConfig.Register**

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Comment: your json should be `[{"firstName":"Vivian","lastName":"Richards","game":0},
          {"firstName":"Diego","lastName":"Maradona","game":"1"}]`. See my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618471/web-api-put-is-recognizing-query-strings-but-not-body/21618545#21618545

Comment: @KhanhTO you are correct about the way the webapi controller is expecting the json. It does work. But it does not completely solve my issue as the data is coming from backbone.js "save". Since that is another issue, I will close this question here.