# What does Web API need to bind models?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Using angular, I send an HTTP request

```
$scope.addFiles = function (files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            $http.post('/api/files/addFiles', JSON.stringify({ testName: "test", someRandomCrap:"asdf"}));
        }
    }
```

I receive the request properly in my controller. However, the response is null:
[image: Null Request :(]

After verifying that the content header is alright and the information was actually sent, I replaced the sample object with a generic object:

[image: It Works!]

Lo and behold. It works! From this, my guess is that Web API could not bind to my object. Which brings me to my question: What does Web API need to bind to an object?

TestObject:

```
public class TestObject
{
    string testName { get; set; }
    string someRandomCrap { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the post is sending `{ testName: "test", someRandomCrap:"asdf"}` and the signature with the `TestObject` probably needs `{ fileName : { testName: "test", someRandomCrap:"asdf"} }`

Comment: Try removing `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @ErikPhilips That doesn't appear to be it. Unless I am missing some case somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.addFiles = function (files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        $http.post('/api/files/addFiles', { testName: "test", someRandomCrap:"asdf"});
    }
}
```

Two things:

- In asp.net api, the whole request body is bound to a parameter so that we **don't need** to specify a property name in the request body. Have a look at this: [web api put is recognizing query strings but not body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618471/web-api-put-is-recognizing-query-strings-but-not-body/21618545#21618545)
- Don't need `JSON.stringify` otherwise it will treat your whole object as a string. In your second picture, the `fileName` is of type string

Also try making your properties public:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public string testName { get; set; }
    public string someRandomCrap { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Let me try that out! Same thing occurs. Generic object gets the data, while the attempt to map it does not

Comment: @Dudemanword: did you clear the browser cache? If it still does not work, try: `[FromBody]TestObject fileName`

Comment: @Dudemanword: in angular, the default content-type header for post is `application/json` (correct) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Check whether your content-type is something different.

Comment: @Dudemanword: I'm not sure, but looks like your need to make your properties public. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just need the object Itself:

```
$scope.addFiles = function (files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        $http.post('/api/files/addFiles',{ fileName: { testName: "test", someRandomCrap:"asdf"}});
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha! There must be a flaw in my logic. Here are my thoughts:
When the Post is called, it is expecting something matching the signature of TestObject. The call was made with that signature. Or is the parameter name a part of that signature?

Comment: you must match the entire object! Inclusing the name of the parameter you are calling

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't appear to work. I can see it be called when I use the generic object, however, the mapping still doesn't take place