# How can I AJAX POST this complex type to my MVC action?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to POST a complex data type up to an MVC controller action, but the data is null or it contains default values.

Here is the client side (it sets the `type` parameter to `data.complexType` [for example, `type: data.complexType`] and posts it up):

[image]

Here is the problem, on the POST action:

[image]

**It gets the complex type just fine from the GET, but how can I now make it POST the same complex type back to the controller such that it no longer contains null or default values?**

Here is my `HomeController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication0.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostComplexType(ComplexType type)
        {
            return Json(new { complexType = type });
        }

        public ActionResult GetComplexType()
        {
            var result = new ComplexType
            {
                TypeOne = 1,
                TypeTwo = "2",
                TypeThree = new ComplexNestedType
                {
                    TypeOne = 1,
                    TypeTwo = "2"
                }
            };
            return Json(new { complexType = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    public class ComplexType
    {
        public Int32 TypeOne { get; set; }
        public String TypeTwo { get; set; }
        public ComplexNestedType TypeThree { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComplexNestedType
    {
        public Int32 TypeOne { get; set; }
        public String TypeTwo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#exampleButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetComplexType", "Home")",
                type: "get",
                error: function () {
                    alert("There was an error calling GetComplexType().")
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("PostComplexType", "Home")",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            type: data.complexType
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("There was an error calling PostComplexType().")
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
<button id="exampleButton" type="button">Example</button>
```

**Edit**: I tried setting `data: data.complexType` directly, but it won't resolve the nested type:

[image]

Comment: try: `data : data.complexType` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618471/web-api-put-is-recognizing-query-strings-but-not-body/21618545#21618545 and add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: @KhanhTO I tried `data: data.complexType`, but it doesn't seem to resolve the nested complex type (see the edit to my question for a picture of what I mean). Also, adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` seems to cause a 500 error (internal server error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use JSON.stringify

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("PostComplexType", "Home")",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(data.complexType),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    error: function () {
         alert("There was an error calling PostComplexType().")
    },
    success: function (data) {
       debugger;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. Most of the times we have to populate these types using values in different controls. This method gives a lot of freedom to do what you want to do with these types.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var complexNestedType = {TypeOne:1, TypeTwo:'2'}
        var complexType = { TypeOne: 3, TypeTwo: '4', TypeThree: complexNestedType };
        var data = { type: complexType };
        var posting = $.post("/Home/PostComplexType", data, function () {
        });
        posting.done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response != null) {
                alert('success');
            } else{
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```